# Would a hardware comparison question count as 'shopping recommendation'?

Tags: support, site-definition

I have a question about motherboards. I wanted to know if there were any downfalls of buying a motherboard that can take am2/am2+ and am3 cpus. Usually you only see am3 CPUs being supported.

Comment: What information do you feel you're lacking from making that decision yourself? *hint, your question can be legit, you just need to find the real question that makes it so*

Comment: Well not alot of board support all three AMD sockets (recent sockets) and this one is really cheap, so I'm wondering if there is a catch. ie. it can hold an AM3 cpu but it won't perform as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it would count as a shopping recommendation, provided you ask in general terms ( What are the gotchas of putting an AM3 CPU on AM2(+) motherboard) instead of very specifics ( eg: Can I buy `<Manufacturer - Model>` to install my `<AM3>` CPU )